# C++ how to implment a stoppable future function call?

Tags: c++

I want to execute a function after a timeout period, something like:

```
sleep(1000); 
doWork();
```

But before the timeout is reached, I can stop the execution in this thread or other thread, like:

```
if(someCondition)
{
    stop the doWork() it is not started.
}
```

Is there any existing std/boost class to do this kind of task?

Comment: just pick some thread-safe queue/stack that you can fill with tasks to perform but also remove tasks from the schedule if some conditions are unmet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a combination of a variable indicating whether the work needs to be done combined with a timed condition variable: you'd wait for the sleep time and if the wait terminates you'd check if the work should be aborted, more sleeping is needed (condition variables can always stop waiting spuriously), or the work can be started:

```
bool                    do_work(true);
std::mutex              mutex;
std::condition_variable condition;

std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> abs_time(
     std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> kerberos;
if (condition.wait_until(kerberos, abs_time, [&]{ return do_work; })) {
    // do the work
}
```

The other thread cancelling the work would acquire a lock for the mutex, set `do_work` to `false`, and `notify_one()` the condition variable.

Answer (score 1):

a mutex will do - thread 1 waits for the mutex, or timeout. If the 2nd thread resets the mutex the 1st thread will stop blocking before the timeout is up.

On Windows you'd typically use an Event to do this, but boost has [condition variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) that seem to do the same thing - communicate a waitable event to another thread.

Comment: Looks like your method is to stop the waiting and execute the function call. But my indention is to stop executing the function.

Comment: you can tell if the condition stops due to triggering rather than timeout, and either run doWork or not as appropriate. The check would go just before the call to doWork, rather than in the other thread though.

Answer (score 0):

That is a neat question, but I think the best solution depends on your application's needs and constraints. For example, can you use a busy wait sleep function that polls the condition, or do you need something that does not use as much of the CPU?

Here is a first stab at a solution that may work for you:

```
#define SLEEP_RESOLUTION 1000 // A value in microseconds

void do_work_with_delay(int delay_time) { // Specify the delay in ms

    bool condition_reached = sleep_and_check(delay_time);

    if (condition_reached) {
        return;
    }

    do_work();
}


bool sleep_and_check(int delay_time) {
    int accumulated_delay = 0;

    while (accumulated_delay < delay_time*1000) { // Loop until we have waited 
                                             // the whole delay_time
        if (someCondition) // Check the condition, return true if it has been met
            return true;

        usleep(SLEEP_RESOLUTION); // Condition not met, sleep and check again next time
        accumulated_delay += SLEEP_RESOLUTION;
    }
    return false; // Return false to show the whole time 
                  // went by without meeting the condition
}
```